# EXTJS Create checkboxes from store content

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
Ext.define('rgpd.view.SAISIE.saisieCategoriePers', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias: 'widget.saisie_categorie_persform',
requires: [
    'Ext.form.Panel',
    'rgpd.store.sCategoriePers'
],
title: 'Ajout d\'une catégorie de personnes',
autoShow: true,
height: 700,
width: 700,
//resizable: false,
layout: 'fit',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Sélection',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                        // create checkbox from store
                    },
                    // other items
```

I have this window containing a tabpanel. I want to display all my store content (could do it with a grid) and be able to select multiple lines using checkboxes. Is this possible ? I didn't find a store property for checkboxfield and checkboxgroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution i found is to use

```
{
    xtype: 'grid',
    store: 'sCategoriePers',
    id: 'gridsaisiecategoriepers',
    title: 'Categories de Personnes',
    multiSelect: true,
    columns: [
        {
            text: 'Id',
            hideable: false,
            dataIndex: 'id',
            autoSizeColumn : true,
            hidden: true
        },
        {
            text: 'Nom',
            dataIndex: 'nom',
            autoSizeColumn : true,
            flex: 1
        },
    ],

    selModel: {
        selType: 'checkboxmodel',
        showHeaderCheckbox: true
    },
    // ...
```

you can then get the selected rows using getSelection()

Answer (score 1):

You could use [checkcolumn](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Check.html) for your scenario. From the API Docs:

> A Column subclass which renders a checkbox in each column cell which
>   toggles the truthiness of the associated data field on click.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'checked',
        width: 70
    },{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        width: 200
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        width: 250
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone',
        width: 120
    }],
    height: 600,
    layout: 'fit',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2hov

Comment: yes but it makes me add an used column in my model. I found an other solution using selModel and selType